# Determining all currently running Apps from a background Service in Android

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-tv

I am working on an app that needs to check If there is any screen saver kind of app is running currently or not, based on that I need to launch my own app. I am very new with Android Development. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

What I tried:

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService( Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> appProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
for(ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo appProcess : appProcesses){
 if(appProcess.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) 
  {
   Log.d("Foreground Apps:::>", appProcess.processName);
  }
}
```

But code not works while my app is minimised for Android 10 and above.

Comment: This information is not available to apps on modern versions of Android, for privacy and security reasons.

Comment: Okay, so any idea how Screen Saver apps determine that there is no activity there by user since a particular time? @CommonsWare

Comment: Android devices turn the screen off after a period of inactivity.

Comment: True, but I am looking above for Android TV not mobile phone that shows screen saver mostly. @CommonsWare

Comment: From what I have seen, across several device models, Android TV devices manage their own screen savers. There is no "app" to detect, even if such detection were possible. Have you tried `ProcessLifecycleOwner`, to see if your app is considered to be in the background?

Comment: @MohdAsim AFAIK there is a system app for handling screen saver (and day dreaming in general) in Android. This package is responsible for deciding which screensaver app to run, when it's time to start day dreaming.  what use-case are you trying to achieve by knowing the screen saver status?